# iPhone crash - how to read logs

Tags: iphone, crash

My app on the iPhone crash sometimes and I can't find why and where. Here is log I have:

```
-[Order bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x335070
 Stack: (
"0   My App                              0x00012de5 My App + 73189",
"1   My App                              0x00013047 My App + 73799",
"2   CoreFoundation                      0x36d15987 __handleUncaughtException + 74",
"3   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x320852d1 _objc_terminate + 128",
"4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x36d783c5 _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 76",
"5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x36d78451 _ZdlPv + 0",
"6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x36d7979f __cxa_throw + 122",
"7   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x32085223 objc_exception_throw + 94",
"8   CoreFoundation                      0x36d18acb -[NSObject doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 174",
"9   CoreFoundation                      0x36d17945 ___forwarding___ + 300",
"10  CoreFoundation                      0x36c72680 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48",
"11  CoreFoundation                      0x36c64bdd CFDataGetBytePtr + 96",
"12  Foundation                          0x337af8db -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:] + 322",
"13  Foundation                          0x337d3651 +[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:] + 52",
"14  My App                              0x0000eef1 My App + 57073",
"15  Foundation                          0x337ada91 -[NSThread main] + 72",
"16  Foundation                          0x338415a1 __NSThread__main__ + 1048",
"17  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x37cb8c1d _pthread_start + 320",
"18  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x37cb8ad8 thread_start + 8"
)
```

Could soneone to help me this understand?

Comment: It will be good...if u post some code related to this error.

Comment: Problem is I have no idea where the error is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the NSKeyedUnarchiver function becomes an object which was not a NSData type.

Answer (score 0):

bialek,

Set breakpoints to find your bug.Where and which line in your code..